# What is this plant with white-spotted thorny leaves from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is this plant with white-spotted thorny leaves from Morocco? Photographed in spring.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinctive leaves identify the plant as Silybum marianum. It is a member of the plant family Asteraceae. It is commonly called "milk thistle". Originating in the Mediterranean region, it has now spread to many places around the world.  The plant in your photo is immature at ground level. These links will give a better idea of the mature plant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silybum_marianum

https://www.google.com/search?q=silybum+marianum&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG46Kj6L7aAhWvpFkKHfYjA0AQ_AUICigB&biw=1097&bih=642